# Как сохранить игровой прогресс в базу данных MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, unity3d

Есть база данных, данных которая хранит имя  пользователя и его id, а также пароль. 
Пользователь логинится в игру, играет, и по нажатию на кнопки "сохранить", его текущий прогресс (положение игрока на карте, количество очков, инвентарь) должен сохранятся в базе данных.
Вопрос - как реализовать сохранение прогресса в  БД? Хранить данные в одной строке(JSON) или для каждого пункта необходимо создать отдельный столбец?

Comment: А зачем вам база данных? Храните в файле. Хранить в базе данных имеет смысл, если вы хотите собирать какую-нибудь статистику по прогрессу. И тогда всё будет зависеть от этой статистики и нативной поддержки json в mysql

Comment: Именно статистика по прогрессу мне и нужна, чтобы можно было иметь доступ к прогрессу с разных устройств

Comment: Тогда смотрите есть ли в вашей базе данных нативная поддержка json. Если нету, то вам нужно определиться с теми колонками, по которым будет осуществляться выборка. Соответственно, навешать индексы. Если же есть поддержка json, то можно всё хранить в одной колонке

Comment: спасибо  вам, я разобрался. В MySQL можно хранить  данные  в формате  JSON,  после сохранения в БД их  можно считать и  распарсить в нужные форматы.То есть какие  данные сохранять можно настроить  на стороне клиента

Answer (score 1):

для каждого пункта необходимо создать отдельный столбец.

Я понимаю, что лень, но впоследствии тебя не раз и не два пробьёт холодный пот при мысли, что ты мог запихнуть все данные в одну ячейку

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,  но можно узнать почему нельзя запихнуть всё в одну ячейку строкой, а потом вычитать эту строку и по ней загрузить сохраненную  сессию??